# Getting users email address in java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, email, servlets

I have a contact us form created in jsp using this code.

```
       <form action="ContactServlet" method="post">
            <p>Your email address: <input name="email"></p>
            <p>Mail subject: <input name="subject"></p>
            <p>Mail message: <textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
            <p><input type="submit"></p>
            <label name="lblMessageSent"></label>
        </form>
```

I configured my servlet to use gmail and also hard coded the username and password for the email to be sent from. The problem is I want the users email to appear as sent from or if its any easier I would show the users email somehow in the email received.

```
        String from = request.getParameter("email");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("adonisokpidi@gmail.com"));

        String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
        message.setSubject(subject);

        String messageContent = request.getParameter("message");
        message.setText(messageContent);

        Transport.send(message);

        response.sendRedirect("contact.jsp");
```

As you can see, the email's from address should be the one from the HTML form's `email` field, but actually all mails are send with the hard-coded username and password.

*Question* #1: How do I make this work?

*Question* #2: How do I make the form display the label with the content message sent in the contact.jsp after the message has been sent.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "_The 'from' variable does nothing as it uses the hard-coded username and password to send the email._" ? As you can see in your code, `from` is the value of the `request parameter "email"`, which comes from the user's input in the form (`<input name="email">`).

Comment: yes exactly but it currently gets nothing from that textbox and thats why I said it does nothing but instead it sends the email from the already configureed username and password. I want to get the content of <input name="email"> and add it as a content of the email. this will show who the sender is or how can I configure the email to send directly from the users email address. thanks

Comment: You're not going to be able to send emails as another user via a third-party mail server without acquiring that user's email password, and you're not going to get that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use your userId and password to send email with gmail, then the from will be your userId (always). You need to send the email with a properly configured SMTP server, and even then it'll be sent with your application's id. To send with an arbitrary email you'd need an "open relay". You probably aren't going to find one on the internet, you could certainly configure one on your own server (but after a few SPAM incidents, it'll probably be blocked).

Answer (score 0):

Code for ContactUs.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="contactus">
<div><span><label>E-mail</label></span>
<span><input name="email" type="text" class="textbox"></span></div>
<div><span><center><input type="submit" class="" value="Submit"></center></span></div>
</form>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Code for Sevlet file - contact.java

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException,ServletException
{String email=request.getParameter("email");
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","");
st=con.createStatement();
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into contact values('"+name+"','"+email+"',"+mo+",'"+msg+"')");
if(i>0)
{RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);}
else{
out.println("please Feel again");
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("contact.jsp");
```